# Using variable names as row names in R

Tags: r

Suppose i have:

```
    Assembly<-t(read.table("E:\\test\\exp1.csv",sep="|",header=FALSE)[1:4416,5])
```

To assign row names im using:

```
    rownames(data)[1]<-"Assembly"
```

where data is a data frame consisting a number of rows similar to aforementioned. Can i do it using a single command?

Comment: I don't see the need to use rownames in R.

Comment: I require it for a certain application where the row names act as identity....

Comment: So you need `rownames(data) <- vector_of_strings_the_same_length_as_the_number_of_rows_of_your_data.frame`.

Comment: For example, i have read a csv file into variable Assembly, after taking its transpose, Assembly will have 1-row and n columns. I want to name the single row again as Assembly

Comment: Doesn't work. is there a way to name a specific column?

Comment: can you pls send the exact syntax after col.names

Comment: assuming the first four columns have no column names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
read.table(text = "1 2 3 4 5 6
                   7 8 9 10 11 12
                   13 14 15 16 17 18", 
             col.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Assembly", "F"))

#    A  B  C  D Assembly  F
# 1  1  2  3  4        5  6
# 2  7  8  9 10       11 12
# 3 13 14 15 16       17 18

t(read.table(text = "1 2 3 4 5 6
                     7 8 9 10 11 12
                     13 14 15 16 17 18", 
             col.names = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "Assembly", "F"))[1:2, "Assembly", drop = FALSE])

#          1  2
# Assembly 5 11
```